# Trying to make Three.js Boxplot Responsive

Tags: javascript, three.js, responsive

I built a simple three.js boxplot that loads individual jpgs for each mesh (bar). The boxplot looks fine on desktop, however on mobile it looks stretched / distorted. Is there a best method to make this responsive?

For the sake of simplicity, I will use an example public url for each mesh.

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="threeBoxPlot"></canvas>

  #threeBoxPlot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10500px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  }

initiateThree();

function initiateThree() {

  let scene, camera, renderer;

  let cubeGroup;

  init();
  animate();

function init() {

const data = [
[49, 33, 30],
[27, 17, 13],
[9, 8, 5, 2]
]

var i = 1;

width = 500
height = 500
fov = 9
aspect = 1/5
near = .1
far = 1000
color = 0x828282  
density = 0.1

loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()

scene = new THREE.Scene(); // ADDED

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
//camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
camera.position.set(50, 30, 50);
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

cubeGeometries = data.map(row => {
return row.map(c => {
  //return new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, c/max, 0.2 );
  return new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(0.2, c / 8, 0.2);
})
})

var materialArray = [];

const cubeMaterialEight = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialEight.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialThree = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialThree.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

 const cubeMaterialTwo = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialTwo.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialSeven = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialSeven.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterial.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialTen = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialTen.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialNine = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialNine.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialFive = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialFive.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialFour = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialFour.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialSix = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new 
THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/
1428/06000501_.jpg')
});
cubeMaterialSix.color.convertSRGBToLinear();


 materialArray.push(cubeMaterialEight, cubeMaterialThree, cubeMaterialTwo, 
 cubeMaterialSeven, cubeMaterial, cubeMaterialTen, cubeMaterialNine, cubeMaterialFive, 
 cubeMaterialFour, cubeMaterialSix); 

materialIndex = -1;

const cubeMeshes = cubeGeometries.map(row => {
return row.map((cubeGeometry, index) => {
 materialIndex += 1;
 return new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, materialArray[materialIndex]); 

}

  )
  });


cubeGroup = new THREE.Group();
data.forEach((row, i, iarr) => {
row.forEach((d, j, jarr) => {
  cubeMeshes[i][j].position.set(
    i / iarr.length - 0.5, 
    //d/max*0.5-0.6,
    d / 8 * 0.5 - 0.6,
    j / jarr.length - 0.5);

  //cubeMeshes[i][j].scale.set(1,4,1);
  cubeGroup.add(cubeMeshes[i][j]);
 })
})

const mainLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 5.0);
mainLight.position.set(10, 10, 10);

mainLight.castShadow = true;
mainLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
mainLight.shadow.radius = 8;

const ambientLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xddeeff, 0x202020, 3);

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
color: 0x0000ff
});

scene.add(cubeGroup);
scene.add(mainLight);
scene.add(ambientLight);

scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(color, near, far);

scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
 antialias: true
});

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

renderer.domElement.id = 'threeBoxPlot';

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); //ADDED 

}

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );
cubeGroup.rotation.y += 0.01;
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
renderer.render( scene, camera );

}


}
```

Comment: [this?](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-responsive.html)

Comment: @gman thank you gman for responding. to be honest i actually did come across this documentation however I am still struggling refactoring my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser window is resized, you should re-calculate the camera's aspect ratio, and resize the renderer. This is the standard that all Three.js examples use:

```js
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize() {
    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
```

Comment: All the three.js examples end up with scrollbars if your DPR is not an integer where as the solution [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-responsive.html) doesn't have that issue.